# Is there any more media in the Firefly/Serenity universe?

Tags: firefly, serenity

I have recently watched the Firefly series and Serenity movie. And for me Firefly is the best TV show ever created.

I have now become a self-styled Browncoat but I want to know more about the 'verse.

I now proudly have:

1. Firefly DVD set with commentaries, behind the scenes etc. and Serenity the move.
2. Firefly/Serenity Panel videos for various comic-cons
3. Serenity comics: Float Out, Shepherd's Tale, Better Days, Those Left Behind, Downtime and The Other Half (Is there any comic I missed????)
4. 10th anniversary [Browncoats Unite](http://www.sciencechannel.com/tv-shows/firefly/about-this-show/10th-anniversary-special.htm).
5. [Map of the verse](http://www.fireflyshipworks.com/map-of-the-verse/map-of-the-verse/)
6. Firefly World - The [Verse in Mumbers](http://store.qmxonline.com/assets/images/serenity/atlasoftheverse/the_verse_in_numbers_v11.pdf).

I am currently trying to get my hands on:

1. R.Tam Sessions
2. Re-Lighting the Firefly

Are there any more media (print or electronic) related to Firefly?

Comment: There might be a new [comic book](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/08/27/firefly-returning-comic-book-dark-horse_n_3822321.html) in the making...

Comment: "Firefly is the best TV show ever created" Is there any way to fish for upvotes more obviously? +1

Comment: There is also a [fluxx](https://www.looneylabs.com/games/firefly-fluxx) edition of firefly that recently released an expansion. The expansion also details cards that don't exist so at least one more expansion must be in the works... Inexpensive and a lot of fun

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefly_media_franchise), you're missing out on the following media:

- A novelization of the film Serenity by Keith R. A. DeCandido
- An original novel titled *My Own Kind of Freedom* by Steven Brust, released under a Creative Commons license. (Note: This one isn't approved by Joss Whedon.)
- A comic: [Serenity: Firefly Class 03-K64 - It's Never Easy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefly_media_franchise)
- [The Serenity role-playing game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serenity_%28role-playing_game%29) mentioned by Stefan.
- If you're into it, there are soundtracks to Firefly and Serenity, respectively.

For more in-depth information you might also be interested into the following books:

- *Firefly: The Official Companion* (Volume One and Volume Two) by Joss Whedon
- *Firefly: Still Flying* by Joss Whedon
- *Investigating Firefly and Serenity* edited by Rhonda V. Wilcox and Tanya R. Cochran, part of the *Investigating Cult TV* series.
- If you still don't have enough material on your hands there's always *Finding Serenity* and *Serenity Found* by Jane Espenson, both part of the *Smart Pop* series.

---

**added on 2014/10/27**
The card game *Tall Card*—which was briefly shown in the episode *Shindig*— will be released by [Toy Vault](http://toyvault.myshopify.com/products/firefly-tall-card-game) in 2015:

[image: Firefly card game: Tall Card]

---

**added on 2015/01/08**
The board game *Fistful of Credits*—which is based on the three heist scenarios depicted in the episodes *Bushwhacked*, *The Train Job*, and *Ariel*—will be released by [Toy Vault](http://toyvault.myshopify.com/products/firefly-fistful-of-credits-board-game) in 2015:

[image: Firefly board game: Fistful of Credits]

---

**added on 2018/10/27**

- *Firefly Encyclopedia* by Monica Valentinelli (ISBN: 9781785655296)
- *Big Damn Hero* by James Lovegrove with Nancy Holder and Joss Whedon (ISBN: 9781785658266, the first novel in a new series titled Firefly)

Comment: Along with the soundtracks, there are some fan made songs and sheet music. The group I was with used to perform some of them at our local renaissance faire. IIRC we did "Into the black", "Jayne's Song" and "River's Jig", the song played during the dance scene in "Our Mrs. Reynolds".

Comment: @JohnP Yeah, I distinctly remember a rendition of Mal's Song by [Vixy and Tony](http://www.vixyandtony.com/). For fan made content YouTube generally is a good place to start looking.

Comment: You missed the Firefly-themed Monopoly game.

Comment: There is also  Firefly:The Board game. https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/138161/firefly-game. Also there is another more recent Firefly RPG using a different rule set than the Serenity one.

Answer (score 24):

There's a comic series of [xkcd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/xkcd), a very popular webcomic, addressing Firefly (basically because Randall is maniac Firefly fan (in the best possible way)).

[image: The Race: Part 1]
[image: The Race: Part 2]
[image: The Race: Part 3]
[image: The Race: Part 4]
[image: The Race: Part 5]

Source:

- http://xkcd.com/577
- http://xkcd.com/578
- http://xkcd.com/579
- http://xkcd.com/580
- http://xkcd.com/581

Comment: Elaborated (on the *Explain xkcd* wiki): [Part 1](http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/577:_The_Race:_Part_1), [part 2](http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/578:_The_Race:_Part_2), [part 3](http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/579:_The_Race:_Part_3), [part 4](http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/580:_The_Race:_Part_4), and [part 5](http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/581:_The_Race:_Part_5).

Answer (score 2):

Have you had a look at the RPG rule book?  It contains a lot of background information.

If you like playing RPGs it is not a bad system too imho.

Comment: Could the divebomber please leave a note to explain what is wrong with the answer?

Comment: Other than it's really a comment, not an answer?

Comment: Op asks for any more print about the verse and the rpg is a print about the verse with background information. In what way is it not an answer?

Comment: It doesn't explain anything. It just aks "have you seen the rule book?" with an opinion of "not too bad". I am not the downvoter, sorry you're all bunched up about it.

Comment: I explained that it contains a lot of background info, which is logically related to firefly which is what the OP asked for. As for being 'bunched up' yep, it kept me awake for hours.

Answer (score 2):

I recently purchased the Firefly blueprints/ plans on eBay. This includes the introduction of the Firefly series (of ships) by the CEO of the Firefly Division of Blue Sun, layouts for the Firefly 03 series , using Serenity as the base. 
There are five crew bunks. Mal's cabin is smaller than Wash & Zoe's. There are at least two shower rooms. Kaylee's bunk is next to Mal's. There is one empty bunk. Simon and River have separate staterooms. There are several airlocks. In addition to the shuttles, there are at least two escape pods. There's also a whole bunch of mechanical stuff that would be useful to fanfic writers.
And two short stories, one told as dialogue on a sort of Cortex "Shadetree Mechanic" program and one as a junkyard logbook. Both amusing. 
The book is 'canon' btw, being authorized by Universal Studios.

Answer (score 0):

In [episode 429](http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/media.blubrry.com/grammargirl/traffic.libsyn.com/grammar/gg_429.mp3) of the *[Grammar Girl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammar_Girl%27s_Quick_and_Dirty_Tips_for_Better_Writing)* podcast the following word from Serenity and Firefly is covered:

- Reaver (14 mins 15 secs - 17 mins 32 secs)

*Reaver* is included in *[Beowulf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beowulf)* (the poem).

Answer (score 0):

There is soooo much Firefly-related goodness right now. In the last 13 years or so, there's never been a better time to be a Browncoat. So much sway, official merchandise and yes - canon friendly narrative. I mean, there's been 3 main comic series already, 4 one-shots tales and 'No Power In The Verse' coming in a month or two. Woop Woop!

Plus, if you have trouble finding Joss's script to read for the unaired 15th episode (Dead or Alive) or any of the behind the scenes stuff and gubbins from the Fox era in 2002/2003 - let me know and I can send them to ya.